# Invalid syntax for integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm receiving this error message when trying to match up integer ID's in my query us Postgres.

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation:ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "matches.team_id"
```

I have associations in place.

**Stat**

```
belongs_to :player
has_many :matches, foreign_key: 'match_id', primary_key: 'match_id'
```

**Match**

```
has_many :stats
has_many :players, through: :stats
```

**Stats Controller**

```
@player = Player.find(params[:id])    
@stats = Stat.where("player_id = ?", @player.id).joins(:matches)
.where('stats.team_id = ?', 'matches.team_id').select('SUM(stats.goals) AS goals')
```

My Matches database has two `match_id` rows that are the same and when I sum out the players goals it finds the players goals, but doubles the `goals` when displaying. So I figured if my query stated that only find where team_id's are the same then it would only generate 1 goal per `match_id`

**Matches db**

```
|id|match_id|team_id|total_score|
|10|  3433  |   1   |     3     |
|11|  3433  |   2   |     2     |
```

**Stats db**

```
|id|match_id|team_id|player_id|goals|
|12|  3433  |   1   |   333   |  1  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
where('stats.team_id = ?', 'matches.team_id')
```

to this:

```
where('stats.team_id = matches.team_id')
```

When you use substitution with `?`, you're saying that the data for `?` should be escaped. It's looking at the type of `'matches.team_id'`, sees that it's a string, and wraps it in quotes.

There may be a way to do that join without needing a custom `where` clause, but the root of your problem is the string escape mechanism.